# How can I show an Message Box after the final dialog in Wix

Tags: wix

We are using Wix V3.10 Toolset to build an .msi setup for our software. On uninstall this is the last dialog:

[image]

Problem: When the user pressed the button "Finish" we want to show an Message Box:

[image]

But the message box will be shown before the "Finish" dialog.

Code:

```
<Custom Action="UninstallConfirmation" OnExit="success">(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>

<CustomAction Id="UninstallConfirmation" Script="vbscript">
  <![CDATA[MsgBox("The software was successfully removed from your computer.")]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Question: How can we show the Message Box after the "Finish" dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to [trigger a custom action from an UI element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html). This example shows how to launch the application when the installation is complete, using a custom action.